# H.264 streaming for IP Camera

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, ip-camera

I am looking for a IP camera simulator  which would support **H.264 streaming**.Currently I found axis emulator for 223M camera but it only support **MJpeg over http** not **H.264**. I have to create a stream(Images) to which MY DVR (with H.264) can access as IP-camera and play the video. (I can see the video on DVR  through Axis emulator[Images as input] with **Jpeg** format only, but I need to run the video with **H.264** format.)

Answer (score 0):

Run a live555 media server http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/ and use a H.264 elementry stream on disk.